# MySQL Bad Handshake to MySQL Cluster behind Proxy

Tags: linux, mysql, load-balancing, connection, mysql-cluster

I have just set up a MySQL cluster using five hyperV linux boxes (2x management nodes, 2 data nodes and 1 proxy) having followed (with a bit of tweaking) the instructions [here](https://www.null-byte.org/development/mysql-ndb-cluster-setup-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/). Everything works fine superficially, I can connect via the proxy to the data, from a MySQL command line on an Ubuntu box without issue, however when I try and connect to the proxy from windows (8.1) using SQLYog or Workbench I get an error no: 1043 - Bad Handshake. I can however, connect directly to the data nodes via workbench/SQLYog?

Is this a common problem, am i missing something obvious? the various OS/MySQL versions are shown below:

MySQLCluster: 7.4.5

MySQL Proxy: amd64/trusty 0.8.1-1.1build1

Ubuntu: 14.04.1 LTS (all boxes, including test from MySQL client)

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like the aptitude version is several versions behind (A colleague pointed it out), Having downloaded and installed the tar from the MySQL site, all is working happily.